# How to get the response text in restangular CustomPOST method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I have an Angular app that uses Restangular library for API and I used `customPOST` method to include additional request data. How can I get the response text data of the response object (like the `name` key below)?

sample response is simple as this `{"name":"5535bfbece3e14381ff3be9d.zip"}`

Answer (score 0):

Provided you get the response in myObj, you can simply get the key as:

```
var myObj = {
 "name": "5535bfbece3e14381ff3be9d.zip"
};
var key = Object.keys(myObj);//this will get the "name" key
```

Refer this [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fLwfL9gw/)